# Passing images as ArrayList<Bitmap> from Fragment to Custom List Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, bitmap

I am not able to send bitmap data from fragment class to custom adapter class. The log show me the following error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.readersden, PID: 21025 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
atjava.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.example.readersden.CardAdapter.getView(CardAdapter.java:82)
```

Fragment class (Inside onPostExecute method of AsyncTask) :

```
            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 

            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf);
            try {
                JSONObject imageInfo = volumeObject.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                new GetBookThumb().execute(imageInfo.getString("thumbnail"));
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                bookThumb.add(0, bmp);
                je.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Fetch Image class (Inside doInBackground method of AsyncTask class) :

```
            InputStream thumbIn = thumbConn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream thumbBuff = new BufferedInputStream(thumbIn);
            thumbImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(thumbBuff);
            bookThumb.add(0, thumbImg);
            thumbBuff.close();
            thumbIn.close();
```

Custom Adapter Class (Inside getView method) :

```
            ArrayList<Bitmap> bookThumb;
            e.thumb.setImageBitmap(bookThumb.get(pos));
```

I am new to android development and it is so much fun! ^.^ thank you!

Edit :

```
public CardAdapter(ArrayList<String> bookTitle,
        ArrayList<String> bookAuthor, ArrayList<String> bookPublishDate,
        ArrayList<String> bookPages, ArrayList<Bitmap> bookThumb,
        Activity mAct) {
        super();
        this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
        this.bookPublishDate = bookPublishDate;
        this.bookPages = bookPages;
        this.bookThumb = bookThumb;
        this.mAct = mAct;

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mAct
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        LayoutField e;
            if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_card, viewGroup, false);
            e = new LayoutField();
            e.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
            e.thumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_thumbnail);
            e.author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
            e.publishDate = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.book_publish_date);
            e.pages = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_pages);
            view.setTag(e);
        } else
            e = (LayoutField) view.getTag();

        e.title.setText(bookTitle.get(pos));
        e.thumb.setImageBitmap(bookThumb.get(pos));
        e.author.setText(bookAuthor.get(pos));
        e.publishDate.setText(bookPublishDate.get(pos));
        e.pages.setText(bookPages.get(pos));

        return view;
    }

    class LayoutField {
        TextView title, author, publishDate, pages;
        ImageView thumb;
    }
}
```

Passing text is working perfectly fine! just the images give index out of bounds.

Comment: more code is req. How are you assigning the arrayList to bookThumb ?

Comment: One of the `*.get(pos)` arrays doesn't have any elements.

Comment: hi! i am assigning bitmap image to arraylist<bitmap> by using bookThumb.add(index, bitmap); method.

Comment: @nija its the arraylist<bitmap> that is throwing the index out of bounds error. possibaly either its null or data is stored in more than one index? is there any exceptions i need to check for? if so.. where?

Comment: @rogerthatcode `bookThumb` has no elements as the exception says `size is 0`. That's the problem. Add logging to where the exception is and where you add to the array to see the order of operation?

Comment: @nija i will update my code with more descripton in few mins. i try to solve it by converting bitmap to byte[] array and then passing it. that does not help either. Im kinda confused :s gimme few minss

Comment: @rogerthatcode I gave a pointer on how to track down the issue. The next step is on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the notifydatasetchanged() at the wrong place i.e before the images were downloaded in the background thread. since my getCount() was returning the number of images.. by the time i called notifydatasetchanged() the ArrayList was not populated (i.e background thread not completed). Hope it helps someone with similer error sometime. thanks everyone for help!